# Compiling and using a function in SQL developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

You might not believe it but I searched the questions on stackoverflow to find an answer for the following question:

I can compile this function

```
create or replace function cart_distance(x1 in number,x2 in number,y1 in number,y2 in number)
return number is
begin
   return sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
end;
```

But if I want to test it the compiler gives the following error "Encountered the symbol SELECT"

```
SELECT cart_distance(2,3,4,5) FROM DUAL;
```

The function and the query are written in the SQL worksheet and I press the "Run statement" option. (I'm very unexperienced with the program)

Comment: It should be: SELECT dbo.cart_distance(2,3,4,5) FROM DUAL;   assuming it's assigned to the dbo schema, and you're using SQL Server.

Comment: This looks like oracle.  select statement looks correct.  Highlight just the select statement and execute that.

Comment: @rono: the syntax is clearly PL/SQL and not T-SQL. And Oracle does not require user defined functions to be prefixed with the schema (owner).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Selecting the query text and pressing the "Run" button. From the error which you have posted, I understand that it is executing the function compilation in the same Run as executing the query. Or better - try in a separate worksheet. Make sure your connection is correct.